# Biggest sum on a square matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

> Given a square matrix of n x n size where each cell is represented by
>   a positive integer, find such a list of n integers from that matrix
>   that the sum of them is as big as possible but no two integers
>   appeared in the same row or column in the initial matrix.

So my best idea was that, since we know that choosing a cell to be added to the sum means all the cells in the same row and column won't be able to get there anymore, we can calculate the "cost" a given cell has. Since the sum of the row is the same for each cell in the row, we may ignore it our calculations. More formally:

```
for each cell in each row:
    if (columnNotYetVisited AND (-1 * sumOfTheColumn) + (2 * valueOfTheCell) > currentMax):
        currentMax = (-1 * sumOfTheColumn) + (2 * valueOfTheCell);

if endOftheRow:
    mark columnWithBestCost as visited;
    add currentMax to finalSum;
```

And while it does work for some inputs, there are some where it fails by quite a large margin. What's the best approach for this problem, then?

EDIT: Also, a sample test I have on me right now in case it comes in handy:

```
7   53  183 439
627 343 773 959
447 283 463 29
217 623 3   399
```

**Edited**
    OUT: 2282 (439 + 773 + 447 + 623)

Comment: could you show me some test cases?

Comment: @Andres - Added one sample to the post :)

Comment: Please also add the numbers for this test case

Comment: also add a case which your code fail

Comment: Added the numbers which make up the sum for the test case. Won't be able to add the test case where my code fails right now as I don't have it at hand currently.

Answer (score 2):

I solved using **dynamic programming** and **bitmask**

```
//                 bitmask      
int F(int stage, int selecion)
{
  if(stage == N) return selecion == (1<<N)-1 ? 0 : -INF;

  if(dp[stage][selecion] != -1)
    return dp[stage][selecion];

  int answer = -INF;

  for(int i = 0;i < N;i++)
    if((selecion & (1 << i)) == 0) 
        answer = max(answer, matrix[i][stage] + F(stage+1, selecion | (1 << i) ) );

  dp[stage][selecion] = answer;

  return answer;
}
```

[here](http://ideone.com/vchrwa) it all my code

I think it can be solve with others algoritms as [hungarian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) but it works well for small matrix(20x20)

If you are interested in programming contests you may want to try [this spoj problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/LINEUP/) (it have a trick case because you can not choose some zero 0)